# Transferring OAuth authentication from mobile app to webview

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I have been working on implementing OAuth in my project's API. As a part of this project, we have a mobile app that authenticates a user via this API, using a password grant (this grant actually sends the given credentials on to an upstream authentication server that doesn't implement OAuth - so it is required).

This mobile app also has the functionality whereby it opens a webview to some pre-determined websites. The idea is that these websites would be able to authorize on behalf of the user using the authorization_code grant.

This is where my question comes in. When authorizing the websites, we obviously require that the user be authenticated with our API. However, the user authenticated via the password grant in the app, and not in the webview.

How would we transfer the authentication from the app to the API when the authentication was done in the app? My thinking is that setting a cookie containing the token on the API's domain would be the best way of implementing this?

Apologies if the question is not as clear as it could be. I'm struggling with how best to phrase and explain my question.

Answer (score 0):

Good question - I have implemented this in the past via a strategy pattern:

- When webview is hosted in a browser (which was an SPA in my case), handle tokens in a standard SPA manner - eg token renewal on an iframe / full screen login redirects
- When webview is hosted in a mobile app, detect this via the user agent and call back the mobile app to do things like refresh a token or initiate a new mobile login

It is tricky but makes sense since web / mobile have very different solutions for token renewal / storage / login

It is the sort of practical real world use case where you find pretty much zero guidance online. Happy to answer any follow up questions.

Comment: When hosting it in a mobile app, are you meaning exposing some kind of native functionality to the webview via JavaScript?

Comment: Yes - JavaScript determines it is running in a web view and then calls back the mobile app - which can do things like use the refresh token to get a new access token and return it to the JavaScript code